# Jquery - EaseOutBounce effect

Tags: jquery, dropdown

I have a problem with my code. When i click on button, nothing happen, just reload the page.

## CSS:

```
#click{
    position: absolute;
    right: 50px;
    top: 30px;
}
.media{
    width: 100px;
    height: 300px;
    background: #ccc;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 80px;
    display: none;
}
```

## HTML:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<button id="click">Button</button>
<div class="media"></div>
```

## JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#click").click(function () {
      $('.media').toggle('slide', {
         duration: 1000,
         easing: 'easeOutBounce',
         direction: 'up'
      });
   });
});
```

Please help to solve this, i dont have more idea.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, make sure you have referenced JQuery:

**Example:**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256 FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

After the click event, you can return false.

```
   $("#click").click(function () {
      $('.media').toggle('slide', {
         duration: 1000,
         easing: 'easeOutBounce',
         direction: 'up'
      });
   });
   return false;
```

or make the following change:

```
   $("#click").click(function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $('.media').toggle('slide', {
         duration: 1000,
         easing: 'easeOutBounce',
         direction: 'up'
      });
   });
```

Reference: https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: I put your script line before my script line as reference and i tried both of your solutions, but doesn't worked. Nothing happen... Any idea?

Comment: I just tried your code and it works. Slides down on click, and slide up on click again.

Comment: What browser are you using? Open developer tools and check your console for errors.

Comment: Now with your event solution i have different effect. If i click on button, the "div" is appear suddenly, and if i click on it again, nothing happen.

Comment: And with your return false solution, if i click, the DIV appear for a very little time and after disappear.

Comment: Go to: https://jqueryui.com/easing/ and run the sample demos. Does the effect show correctly?

Comment: Like I mentioned before, your jsfiddle posted earlier works. Check developer console for errors. Make sure JQuery has loaded and DOM is ready.

Comment: I tested, result:

Comment: TypeError: w.easing[this.easing] is not a function[További tudnivalók] jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2:55877
run
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2:55877
u
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2:59193
w.fx.tick
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2:62636
at
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2:56975

Comment: Try jquery-2.2.1.min.js instead.

Comment: Get an error on Console something like this: "Loading mixed active "http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js" content blocked"

Comment: And one more: The integrity attribute hashe has been badly formatted in the script element

Comment: Now it works, i just put this: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> instead of previous. But your event solution helped too, that needed too. Thanks for helping. ;)